# wi-fi speed test android

Tags: client-server, download, wifi, speed-test

I'm trying to make an android application ,that tests the Wi-Fi speed, well to do that i need to upload and download a file ,to test the speed.
Well i read that i need two phones ,the first one will be the client ,and the second one will be the server.
But ,i want to use only one android phone to test the speed through the AP, it mean's that the phone will play the role of the client and the server in the same time ,well i don't know if it  a feasible thing or not ,please can someone tell me if it is feaseible or not ?
Well this idea came to me in case when someone have just only one phone and he want to know his Wi-Fi speed.
PS: i don't want a loopback test.
Thank you in advance.